# Putting a phrase like "in particular" before a negative statement

Tags: word-order, subject-verb-inversion

In a sentence starting with a word like *nowhere*, inversion is necessary like in the sentence

> Nowhere in this document is the use of other instruments even mentioned.

But what happens if I add a phrase like "in particular"?

> In particular, nowhere in this document is the use of other instruments even mentioned.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would maintain the inversion. The addition of an adverbial clause separated by a comma normally does little to change the rest of the sentence. At any rate, I have to say I would not start a sentence with *in particular, nowhere...* If you must use *in particular* there, you could recast the sentence.

Comment: 'In particular, the use of other instruments is nowhere mentioned in this document' - sounds better.

Comment: @WS2: Yes, exactly, a reshuffle.